# Make root site offline while keeping subsite online

Tags: sharepoint

Scenario:

SharePoint 2010:

We have one site collection in which we have one Root site and one subsite under it, we need to restrict user access to root site while keeping subsites available, Is there any OOTB way to acheive this instead of doing it through Urls etc.

Root site:   ~siteUrl/
Subsite:      ~siteUrl/Operations

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to break permission inheritance, remove users from the root site and provide them to the link to the subsite.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any alternate approach bcoz i dnt want to make any change in the root site, as we might need to make it online some day

Comment: You could add a redirect page on the root site that would always send them to the sub site?